# How to get a bibtex-bibliography and a selfwritten "\bibliography" element together?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've got **an external .bib file**, which is written in bibtex and i can't add some elements into, because i just have the read permissions on it. When i build **a bibliography element for my additional content**, **two indexes will be displayed**..How can i tell Latex, that it should build the both indexes together?

Answer (score 5):

Create another file, `mybibliography.bib` and call both:

```
\bibliography{theirbibliography,mybibliography}
```